# What's the best way to find the first common parent of two DOM nodes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, selection, getselection

My question is exactly that but in context I want to examine the selection object, compare the anchorNode and focusNode and if they are different then find the first common parent element.

```
var selected = window.getSelection();
var anchor = selection.anchorNode;
var focus = selection.focusNode;

if ( anchor != focus ) {
   // find common parent...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try something like this, assuming no JS library:

```
function findFirstCommonAncestor(nodeA, nodeB, ancestorsB) {
    var ancestorsB = ancestorsB || getAncestors(nodeB);
    if(ancestorsB.length == 0) return null;
    else if(ancestorsB.indexOf(nodeA) > -1) return nodeA;
    else if(nodeA == document) return null;
    else return findFirstCommonAncestor(nodeA.parentNode, nodeB, ancestorsB);
}
```

using this utilities:

```
function getAncestors(node) {
    if(node != document) return [node].concat(getAncestors(node.parentNode));
    else return [node];
}

if(Array.prototype.indexOf === undefined) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(element) {
        for(var i=0, l=this.length; i<l; i++) {
            if(this[i] == element) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

Then you can call `findFirstCommonAncestor(myElementA, myElementB)`.

Comment: Thanks for the library free version though you've both been a big help!

Answer (score 11):

Since this question and accepted answer are very dated, I'd like to suggest using a more modern DOM API, [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range):

```js
function findFirstCommonAncestor(nodeA, nodeB) {
    let range = new Range();
    range.setStart(nodeA, 0);
    range.setEnd(nodeB, 0);
    // There's a compilication, if nodeA is positioned after
    // nodeB in the document, we created a collapsed range.
    // That means the start and end of the range are at the
    // same position. In that case `range.commonAncestorContainer`
    // would likely just be `nodeB.parentNode`.
    if(range.collapsed) {
        // The old switcheroo does the trick.
        range.setStart(nodeB, 0);
        range.setEnd(nodeA, 0);
    }
    return range.commonAncestorContainer;
}
```

Comment: For those of you wondering about browser support for `Range`, even IE9 supports it, thats how long ago (around 2012) it was implemented in browser: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_range

Answer (score 1):

This way is fairly straightforward:

```
var fp = $(focus).parents();
var ap = $(anchor).parents();
for (var i=0; i<ap.length; i++) {
  if (fp.index(ap[i]) != -1) {
    // common parent
  }
}
```

Loop through the [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of one element and see if they are contained in the `parents()` of the other using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) until you find a match (or not).

Comment: Very tidy - I may have to get some jquery on the case in this project, starting to look worth it now.

Comment: @sanchothefat oh my bad, sorry for some reason I thought your question was jQuery-related.

Comment: No worries. Pretty much all javascript is jquery related these days (or should be)

Answer (score 1):

// It seems like it should be fairly simple, even without a library or indexOf

```
document.commonParent= function(a, b){
 var pa= [], L;
 while(a){
  pa[pa.length]=a;
  a= a.parentNode;
 }
 L=pa.length;
 while(b){  
  for(var i=0; i<L; i++){
   if(pa[i]==b) return b;
  }
  b= b.parentNode;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a a good bit of DOM API for that: [compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)

This is how it goes:

```
    /**
     * Returns closest parent element for both nodes.
     */
    function getCommonParent(one, two){
        let parent = one.parentElement;
        if(one === two) { //both nodes are the same node.
            return parent;
        }
        const contained = Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY;
        let docpos = parent.compareDocumentPosition(two);

        while(parent && !(docpos & contained)) {
            parent = parent.parentElement;
            docpos = parent.compareDocumentPosition(two);
        }
        return parent;
    }
```